# Sitecore Logs - Azure Search

Tags: azure, sitecore8

Currently I'm seeing the following a lot in my logs, I'm using Sitecore 8.2 rev 2 with azure.  The issue only started recently when I added some new indexes to the site for a new microsite.  Any ideas of where to start investigating, I've raised with Sitecore too?

```
ManagedPoolThread #17 22:03:10 ERROR Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Source: mscorlib

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.

Source: mscorlib

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`2 body)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1 indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Sequence contains no elements

Source: System.Core

   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.Delete(IIndexableId id)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass93_2.<PerformUpdate>b__0(IndexableInfo info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a patch for this from Sitecore, hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those with the same issue,
The patch is Sitecore.Support.158988 found here:
https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.158988
Versions cover Sitecore 8.2 update 1 and update 2.

> 164633 The CloudSearchUpdateContext.Delete(IIndexableId) fails with an exception in case the search index does not contain any matching documents.

Thanks.